# Django reading from file uploaded via website

Tags: javascript, django, file-io

I want to make a web site where you can choose a local file (XML/JSON) and then proceed to a Django view that will read data out of it. Should I use javascript for choosing form and to send file to specific URL (for Django view)? How to do that? Any examples?

I started from [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you use javascript or not, the Django aspect will still be the same.  You'll have a django view that handles a post with your file.  Assuming you are using `<input type="file" name="" />`, you can access your file through `request.FILES`.  See the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES).

A quick example of what your view would do:

```
def view_handling_file(request):
    file_name = request.FILES['input_name'].name #input_name refers to the name attr in your file input
    file_data = request.FILES['input_name'].read()
    # do stuff with your file
```

With the page that allows your users to select a file, you can either have it just submit.  Or you can use javascript to make the post request via ajax.  You may need to use a jquery plugin like `jquery-iframe-transport` to pass files via ajax.  It'll be easier to just have your form submit.

Comment: I used that kind of form (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560949/using-javascript-and-django-to-upload-a-text-file-to-some-folder-in-server), but I don't receive any FILES, request holds only POST data (csrfmiddlewaretoken and my input)

Comment: OK, got it, just forgot to add enctype in form ;)